# Probability measure induced by a measurable function of a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, measurable-functions

Suppose there are two random variables X and Z: $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mathbb{P}) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{B}) $, a measurable function $g: \mathbb{R} \times  \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and assume $\mathbb{P}^{(X,Z)} =\mathbb{P}^{(Z,X)} $.

I read in some proof, that it follows that $\mathbb{P}^{g(X,Z)} =\mathbb{P}^{g(Z,X)}$ but I don't understand why.

Thanks!

Comment: What's $\mathbb{P}^Y$?

Comment: Sorry, $\mathbb{P}^Y(B) := \mathbb{P}(Y \in B)$ for any B from the sigma field.

Comment: Hint: Note for $B \in \mathbb{B}$$$g(X,Z) \in B \iff (X,Z) \in g^{-1}(B),$$ where since $g$ is measurable, $g^{-1}(B)$ is in $\mathbb{B} \times \mathbb{B}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To say that $\mathbb{P}^{(X,Z)} =\mathbb{P}^{(Z,X)}$ means that for every Borel set $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$, $$\mathbb{P}((X,Z)\in A)=\mathbb{P}((Z,X)\in A).$$  To say that $\mathbb{P}^{g(X,Z)} =\mathbb{P}^{g(Z,X)}$ means that for every Borel set $B\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, $$\mathbb{P}(g(X,Z)\in B)=\mathbb{P}(g(Z,X)\in B).$$  To prove the second statement from the first, just observe that $g(X,Z)\in B$ iff $(X,Z)\in g^{-1}(B)$ and similarly for $(Z,X)$, so you can just set $A=g^{-1}(B)$.